# Filling calendar with blank cells

Tags: php, calendar

I have the following (simplified) code for creating a calendar in PHP (month view).

```
<?php

$d = date_Parse_from_format('Y-m-d',date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET['date'])));

// month from date
$month = $d['month'];

// year from date
$year = $d['year'];

// days in month
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);

// first day
// if sun (7) => 0
// else +1
$firstDay = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-1'));

if($firstDay == 7){

    $firstDay = 1;

}else{

    $firstDay = $firstDay+1;

};

// last day
$lastDay = $days;

// start day = 1
$day = 1;

// start cell = 1
$cell = 1;

echo '<table border="1" width="700">';

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td>';

echo '</tr>';

for($row=0;$row<ceil((($lastDay+$firstDay)-1)/7);$row++){

echo '<tr>';

for($col=1;$col<=7;$col++){

    if($day > $days){ break; };

    if($cell < $firstDay){

        echo '<td></td>';

        $cell++;

    }else{

        echo '<td>'.$day.'</td>';

        $day++;

    };

};

echo '</tr>';

};

echo '</table>';

?>
```

The first cells not belonging to the month are filled in blank, that works correctly, but at the end of the table there is a break. I want to fill in the remaining days of that row with a blank cell, but I cant figure it out how.

I think it has to be here, but how:

```
if($day > $days){ break; };
```

I hope the question is clear, sorry for my English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the code from loop

```
if($day > $days){ break; };
```

change the if condition to

```
if($cell < $firstDay || $day > $days){
```

i tested it.